# Can you manipulate a WebSocket connection of your browser with javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket

I'm trying to "manipulate" an existing WebSocket connection of the browser.

For example: I visit the page example.com which creates a websocket connection with my browser.

Is there any way to access this connection and send data from javascript?

Comment: Javascript running where?

Comment: I'd like to do it from the console right now

Comment: Yes! Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Comment: In other words, You want to hijack an existing web socket connection? hmmm im not sure about the legality of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to use your own Javascript to send data on a webSocket that the webpage's Javascript opened, then you will have to "hack" into the variables of the webpage to find how/where it stores the webSocket that it opened up.  It would take some sleuthing through the site's Javascript to see how practical/possible that was.  There is no "standard" way that a webSocket is stored in a page that allows you to just get it from there.  You'd have to get it from the existing Javascript.  If it's stored inside a closure, then it may not even be possible to get it from the console.

Or, you could just open your own webSocket to the page's server from the console and do whatever you wanted to do with your own webSocket using your own Javascript from there.  You don't have to use the webSocket that the page opened as long as you can see from the Javascript in the page how it opens the webSocket and anything that might need to be sent in order to initialize the webSocket properly.

I would also suggest that you observe all applicable laws, licenses and terms of service.

Comment: @Zazama - did this answer your question?